# R - Merge 10 pages into one dataframe using FOR-loop or a WHILE-loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, while-loop

I need to combine 234 review data into one.

## --

But I have to do this automatically by using a loop

Does anyone has any idea's?

Answer (score 2):

Even better, you can use `lapply`:

```
do.call("rbind", lapply(1:10, function(x) data.frame(getReviews(368677368, "us", x))))
```

Or, with a `for` loop:

```
db_list <- list()
for(i in 1:10)
{
 db_list[[i]] <- data.frame(getReviews(368677368, "us", i))
}
final_result <- do.call("rbind", db_list)
```

---

Comment: @JoeBens if `getReviews` returns a data frame, then the second code I showed should leave a single data frame in `final_result`

Comment: @JoeBens I know how you want it to look. But `output` isn't part of my answer. If you run the second code block in my answer above, `final_result` should be a single data frame. In your demo, you just show me `output`, which is equivalent to my `db_list`. You should be able to get the result you want from `do.call("rbind", db_list)` or `do.call("rbind", output)`

Answer (score 2):

I didn't know what your function `getReviews` did, so I stubbed it in:

```
getReviews <- function(pp_id, country, page_num){
  data.frame(pp_id, country, page_num)
}
```

Here's the `for` loop.

```
output <- NULL  # Best practice is to pre-declare
cases <- 1:10
for(i in seq_along(cases)){        # seq_along is better 
  output[[i]] <- getReviews(368677368, "us", i)
}
bind_rows(output)
```

Ref: *R for Data Science*, H Wickham, 1st ed, p 314

Comment: @JoeBens, I thought you _wanted_ 10 data frames.  I edited it, added `bind_rows`.

But you really ought to be using `map_df` instead of a `for` loop.